# How to implement Calendar using collectionview in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad, calendar, uicollectionview

I am looking to implement a calendar with month view & to be able to add appointments to day, as in attached image. Suggest me with some example to approach this, Thank you in advance!

[image: Calendar view in ipad]